# Navigation bar disappears while navigating back from search page to home page using SWreveal view cntroller in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationbar, swrevealviewcontroller

Here i had navigation bar in home page i.e front view controller and in home page i am having navigation bar and search bar also in navigation after tapping on search bar it moves to search page which is not having any navigation and if i dismiss from search page home page navigation disappears can anyone help me how to place navigation bar for home page while coming back from any view controllers in swift 3 ?

Here is my image shown below

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/32094391/41342703-82c64c24-6f1a-11e8-89e9-ebd35066e7d2.png

The code used is shown below

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let abcViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "filterPage") as! filterPageViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(abcViewController, animated: true)
 }
```

The code for coming back from search page is

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
   self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: are you hide anywhere in your navigation bar in search page

Comment: yes in search page i don't need any navigation bar so i am hiding navigation bar @Anbu.karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you need to hide or make your navigation bar visible on your ViewController(VC), you simply do that in the “**viewWillAppear**” and “**viewWillDisappear**” functions

on your home VC, add the following line

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(true)

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

or in your search page viewWillDisappear enable navigation bar

```
 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

// Show the Navigation Bar
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```